# why is pycharm giving 'end of statement expected ' error

Tags: python-3.x

unexpected error even though there is no syntax error in the statement.

i have tried restarting Pycharm.
i tried coping and pasting the code into new tab where every word is pasted in a new line somehow.
can anyone help me find the issue?

this is the image of the error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx8qZ.png

Comment: Please read about the Python variable naming requirements. Afterwards, you shall be able to resolve the issue by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the name of your variable doesn't contain any spaces. I recommend using snake or camel casing.

```
total_number_of_times = 1 #snake
totalNumberOfTimes = 1 #camel
```